# MySQL LIKE Usage One Than More Columns

Tags: mysql, search, sql-like

I want to select records from my table. I want to use this query:

```
select * 
from crawler.crawler_data 
WHERE name_surname, category, description LIKE "%de%";
```

But MySQL doesn't accept this query. I want to search all columns with `LIKE`. How can I write this query to search more than one column with `LIKE` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT`:

```
SELECT * FROM crawler_data WHERE CONCAT(name_surname, category, description) LIKE "%de%";
```

So it is concatenating all the columns you want to check into a single column.

There maybe times where this is unsuitable, where the string you're looking for can be found crossing the split between two columns, so giving you a false positive.

To solve this you can use `CONCAT_WS` which is ***Concatenate with Seperator***. So:

```
SELECT * FROM crawler_data WHERE 
CONCAT_WS('-',name_surname, category, description) LIKE "%de%";
```

Obviously, setting the seperator value (`-`) to being some sort of string that you will not have in the search term (`de`).

Reference: [MySQL Manaul](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)